# Integration Facebook SDK to Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question regarding integration `Facebook SDK` into `Android` app. I have a client, which wants me to integrate `Facebook SDK` into his application, in order to be able to make ads to promote his application in Facebook. Should client create his own `Facebook developer account`? or it's possible to add that app to my `Facebook developer account`? Would be client able promote his app through `Facebook` if the app would be added to my `Facebook developer account`? How to do it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client should have his own or his company's developer account and be given full access.

Comment: How can he give me full access to that facebook developer account? By giving me password and login? Or is that possible somehow to add me as a developer there?

Comment: Yes, since you're working for him, he should give you access to his or his company's developer account. Facebook has a feature that will allow him to add you as a developer to his app, which doesn't require him to give you an ID or password.This is to ensure a smooth transition if in the future should the development be taken over by someone else.

Comment: That's awesome! Where is exactly in the account is possible to add a developer ?